# Home page losing theme after migrating host

Tags: php, mysql, drupal, linode

I have migrated a Drupal application from our self host to a linode VPS a few days ago. After the migration I found that the home page and a few other pages are not loading the custom theme we have been using.

On the new host, I have installed LAMP stack. I used mysqldump to backup the mysql database and moved over to the new host and restore it. For the Drupal code I also make sure the hidden .htaccess file is copied over and preserved all the original setting.

PHP version are the same on both host. Drupal version of the app is 7.20.

You can see the site on the old host: http://www.impact-marketinggroup.com/
and the site on the new Linode VPS: http://www.impactdigitalgroup.com/

The home page and the about-us page are missing styles so far.. Still can't figure out why!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured that curl is not enabled on the new host. After enabled that everything is working proprely.

Thanks.